# Mock Runtime.getRuntime() - Spring Boot - JUnit

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I tried to mock my Runtime.getRuntime() with the following code :

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Runtime.class);
PowerMockito.when(Runtime.getRuntime()).thenReturn(mockRuntime);
```

But I had the following error :

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try like below:

```
   PowerMockito.mockStatic(Runtime.class);
   when(Runtime::getRuntime).thenReturn(mockRuntime);
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I have the following error : Object is not a functional interface